# Swift BackTracking N-queen

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I am trying to solve the N-queen problem.
You can find the problem in https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens/.

For Backtracking, I have learned that we can solve the problem with three keys:

1. Make Choices
2. Constraints
3. Goal

So I came up with this solution:

```swift
func solveNQueens(_ n: Int) -> [[String]] {

    typealias ChessBoard = [[Int]]
    var result = Set<ChessBoard>()


    func getIndexsOfDiagonal(row:Int,column:Int) -> [(row:Int,col:Int)] {
        var indexs = [(Int,Int)]()

        var rowIndex = row
        var colIndex = column

        while rowIndex < n && colIndex < n {
            indexs.append((rowIndex,colIndex))
            rowIndex += 1
            colIndex += 1
        }

        rowIndex = row
        colIndex = column

        while rowIndex >= 0 && colIndex >= 0  {
            indexs.append((rowIndex,colIndex))
            rowIndex -= 1
            colIndex -= 1
        }

        rowIndex = row
        colIndex = column

        while rowIndex >= 0 && colIndex < n {
            indexs.append((rowIndex,colIndex))
            rowIndex -= 1
            colIndex += 1
        }

        rowIndex = row
        colIndex = column

        while rowIndex < n && colIndex >= 0 {
            indexs.append((rowIndex,colIndex))
            rowIndex += 1
            colIndex -= 1
        }
        return indexs
    }

    func placeQuees(chessboard:ChessBoard,row:Int,column:Int) ->ChessBoard {
        var newChessBorad = chessboard
        //set row
        for index in 0..<n {
            newChessBorad[row][index] = -1
        }
        //set column
        for index in 0..<n {
            newChessBorad[index][column] = -1
        }
        //set diagonal
        for index in getIndexsOfDiagonal(row:row,column:column) {
            newChessBorad[index.row][index.col] = -1
        }

        newChessBorad[row][column] = 1

        return newChessBorad
    }

    func solve(chessboard:ChessBoard, queens: Int) {

        if queens == 0 {
            //Goal
            result.insert(chessboard)
        }

        for row in 0..<n {
            for col in 0..<n {
                //Choices
                if chessboard[row][col] == 0 {
                    //Constraints
                    let new = placeQuees(chessboard: chessboard, row: row, column: col)
                    solve(chessboard: new, queens: queens - 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    solve(chessboard: Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: n), count: n), queens: n)


    return result.map {
        //chessboard
        $0.map {
            //row to string
            $0.reduce("") { string,value in
                if value == 1 {
                    return string + "Q"
                } else {
                    return string + "."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it hits time limited. So I am wondering whether my solution is using Backtracking?  What goes wrong, How can I improve the solution, How can we Solve the Backtracking problem? What defines Backtracking?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @vacawama I Know the idea, But I want to know what goes wrong with my solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), since it is concerned around how to improve an already working code. Before asking your question there, please make sure that you check that site's help page making sure you formulate your question in a way that it is on-topic according to that site's rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is backtracking.  It backtracks when it can no longer find an available space (`chessboard[row][col] == 0`) to place a queen.  Since it is finding all possible solutions, it also backtracks after it finds a solution and inserts it into the `result`.

Your solution is merely trying too many trial positions in each call to `solve`.  Note that there can only ever be one queen on any given row.  Because of this, `solve` can work more efficiently by only trying to place queens on a single row in each call to `solve`.  In the first call to `solve`, try placing the queen on `row 0`.  Then, you'll only be considering `n` possible placements instead of `n * n`.  On the second call to `solve`, try placing the queen on `row 1`.  The current `row` can be computed as `n` minus the number of queens remaining or `n - queens`.

With this slight modification, your code runs much faster and successfully passes when submitted to LeetCode:

```
func solve(chessboard:ChessBoard, queens: Int) {

    if queens == 0 {
        //Goal
        result.insert(chessboard)
    }
    else {
        let row = n - queens
        for col in 0..<n {
            //Choices
            if chessboard[row][col] == 0 {
                //Constraints
                let new = placeQuees(chessboard: chessboard, row: row, column: col)
                solve(chessboard: new, queens: queens - 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```